# Change of Variable in Conditional Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian

I'm trying to find the expression for posterior probability $$f_R(r|z)=\frac{f_Z(z|r)f_R(r)}{f_Z(z)}$$ where Z, R and W are random variables, R and W not necessarily independent and Z = R + W.

Since `W = Z - R`, is it legit to conclude :
$$f_Z(z|r) = f_W(z - r|r)?$$

My gut feeling is yes but I can't justify this...

Also, does W and R being independent or not affect the conclusion?

Please provide theory to back up your thoughts and thanks for anyone to help me!

---

Update: 22:59 07-Dec-2019

Answer provided in the comment, conclude later...

Comment: Is it because when we talk about ```f<sub>Z</sub>(z|r)```, we are talking about the probability of values of the random variable Z given a fixed value of random variable R, r?

Comment: $F_Z(z|r) = P(Z\leq z |r) = P(W+R \leq z |R=r) = P(W+r \leq z|r) = P(W \leq z-r|r) = F_W(z-r)$. Differentiate both sides in $z$ and you have it

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Thank you very much! Could you plz elaborate on the step $P(W+R\leq z|R=r) \implies P(W+r\leq z|r)$? If we substitute r into R, why do we still keep the "conditioned by r" bit at the end? Really appreciate your patience.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst  I ran into this stage before and it got me stuck as well, it would really help if you can explain this!

Comment: the meaning is the same

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Maybe I should ask more clearly, how is $P(W+r\leq z|r)$ different from $P(W+r\leq z)$? Ah, the former one is the latter divided by P(R=r)?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I think I get it now, thank you very much!

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I think I'm confused again. Did you mean $P(W+r \leq z|r)$ and $P(W+r \leq z)$ are the same? Is it because that r in  $P(W+r \leq z)$ implicitly implies that this event is conditioned on R=r? What confused me was my previous thought that $P(W+r \leq z)$ is equivalent to $P(W+R \leq z,R=r)$(joint probability). Is this idea wrong?

Comment: $P(W+r \leq z|r)$ is not the same as $P(W+r \leq z)$, which is shorthand for $P(W+r \leq Z, R=r)$ as you said

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Great! It's clear now then. Ta!